# Can I measure actual memory usage of a thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, memory

If yes, I would apreciate an example in Delphi.

I already tried using [TMemoryManagerState](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.TMemoryManagerState) and [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you will be able to track memory with ScaleMM (https://code.google.com/p/scalemm/) as it allocates memory by thread. Out of the box it doesn't have what you need but there are places where you can add it.

If I look at the code, you can either walk the memory lists yourself when you need to get the amount of memory allocated or hook into the TThreadMemManager.GetMem, TThreadMemManager.FreeMem and TThreadMemManager.FreeMemFromOtherThread calls. This code is in the ScaleMM2.pas file. It should be pretty easy to add a memcount to the TThreadMemManager as there is already one per thread. For the other alternative I would look at the code in TMediumThreadManager.ReleaseAllFreeMem to see how it walks the list. You could do something similar and get a list of allocated RAM at any point in time.

Be a bit careful of this as things like block sizes and fragmentation could mean that you get misleading results.

Here is some of the changes to ScaleMM2 that will return memory usage for each thread:

I added a variable called TotalAllocated to TThreadMemManager:

```
  FSmallMemManager : TSmallMemThreadManager;
  FMediumMemManager: TMediumThreadManager;
  FLargeMemManager : TLargeMemThreadManager;
  FTotalAllocated: Int64;
protected
```

I then added the following 2 lines to the bottom of FreeMem:

```
  {$IFDEF SCALEMM_DEBUG}
  CheckMem(nil);
  {$ENDIF}
  FTotalAllocated := FTotalAllocated + pm.Size;
end;
```

and GetMem:

```
  {$IFDEF SCALEMM_DEBUG}
  CheckMem(nil);
  {$ENDIF}
  FTotalAllocated := FTotalAllocated + aSize;
end;
```

I created a global list called FThreadManagerList:

```
FThreadManagerList: TList<PThreadMemManager>
```

And then at the start of the threads that I wanted to check I added the following code:

```
var
  threadManager: PThreadMemManager;
begin
  threadManager := GetThreadMemManager;
  Synchronize(
    procedure
    begin
      FThreadManagerList.Add(threadManager);
    end);
```

After that, getting the memory for the threads was as simple as this:

```
for I := 0 to FThreadManagerList.Count - 1 do
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(FThreadManagerList[I].FThreadID)+' : '+IntToStr(FThreadManagerList[I].FTotalAllocated));
end;
```

I didn't look into the cross thread allocations, you will need to do a bit of research and see how those work. I also didn't look for any race conditions but I don't think that will be a problem either unless one of your threads exits. It should give you something to start with.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by allocate memory by thread. Are you saying that such memory is somehow private to the allocating thread? That sounds implausible. So what do you mean?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What ScaleMM does is have a different memory manager per thread. Each time a thread requests memory ScaleMM will go and get the memory manager for that thread and then use that to request memory. They have some logic for handling cross thread releases, etc. I have not used the library but it should help the OP to track the memory for each thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's not really private. The memory is obviously allocated to the process as a whole. What ScaleMM does is internally keep track of the threads that the memory is allocated to.

Comment: I've tried this solution by creating an event listener inside ScaleMM2, it didn't worked because I needed to create a list to track the threads, this call of Create calls GetMem again creating an infinite recursion.

Comment: @MarceloGimenes You don't need to create and event listener or a list. I have added some code that I used for some basic testing.

Answer (score 10):

Threads don't use memory per se. Processes own memory which is shared between threads. Memory can, and often is, allocated in one thread and used in another.  So the question that you ask is ill-defined.

That said, you could certainly track the allocations and deallocations made by particular threads. You could install a memory manager that tracked heap allocations and stored the number of bytes allocated in a dictionary indexed on thread ID.

Use `GetMemoryManager` and `SetMemoryManager` to inject your allocation counting memory manager into the runtime. The idea is that you make a note of the original memory manager by calling `GetMemoryManager`. You then use `SetMemoryManager` to replace inject your memory manager. Your memory manager tracks allocations, and delegates the actual allocations to the original memory manager.

Answer (score 9):

In Delphi, with the Delphi's standard memory manager (FastMM), this will not be possible. FastMM does not care from which thread memory was allocated.

Some other memory manager *may* offer this capability.